# Multiple DTMF digits

Tags: restcomm

I'm using restcomm-android-sdk and I'm wondering what is the proper way to send multiple DTMF.

1. Can I send multiple DTMF digits in one INFO? (e.g. `DeviceImpl().GetInstance().SendDtmf("1234");`)
2. Can I send multiple DTMF in separate INFO without waiting for the ACK first?

My observation is that neither works properly, but I was not able to find (on Google) how to do this properly.

What worked for me is to send one digit at a time and wait for ACK.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: You 're right, currently the restcomm-android-sdk supports sending DTMF digits one by one, check https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/blob/master/restcomm.android.client.sdk/src/main/java/org/mobicents/restcomm/android/sipua/impl/SipManager.java#L630. But should be pretty straight forward to enhance it to support sending multiple in the same INFO message. This could be a very useful addition to SDK, by the way :). Would you like to take a shot at it and contribute? I can guide you through the process.

Comment: By the way, sending one INFO after the other should work, without waiting for a 200 OK from the previous

Comment: @atsakiridis Yes, basically I wanted to discuss how to implement this, not sure if this is the right place to do so.

Comment: Great, you can open an issue at https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/issues with any enquiries you may have and we can discuss it over there to be easier to track.